# Macro written in Excel 2010 not working in Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a simple macro to force end users to view an EULA and then click a command button to accept the terms. On clicking the tabs for the workbook open allowing the user to work through the book. This works fine in Excel 2010 and all previous version but not in Excel 2013.

I get this error: 
[image: Error Dialogue]

This is the code:

```
Sub OpenSheets()
'
' OpenSheets Macro
'

'
    Sheets("EULA").Select
    Sheets("Infection_Worksheet").Visible = True
    Sheets("Infection_Worksheet").Select
    Sheets("Exit_Site_Infection_Chart").Visible = True
    Sheets("Exit_Site_Infection_Chart").Select
    Sheets("Peritonitis_Chart").Visible = True
    Sheets("Exit_Site_Infection_Chart").Select
    Sheets("%_Pts_peritonitis_free").Visible = True
    Sheets("%_Pts_peritonitis_free").Select
    Sheets("Pt_numbers").Visible = True
    Sheets("Pt_numbers").Select    
    Sheets("Results").Visible = True
    Sheets("Results").Select
    Sheets("Instructions").Visible = True
    End Sub
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: In xl2016, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcIjZ.png) error if I try to unhide a worksheet that is within a workbook with a protected structure.

Comment: Are you somehow dealing with a workspace? The workspace was abandoned in xl2013 when MS moved to independent application windows (within a single application instance).

Comment: The macro runs and opens all the tabs and throws the error I listed above at the end then XL2013 crashes.

Comment: Can you tell us on which line you get the error?

Answer (score 0):

Underscores represent continuation to the next line in VBA.

Try this `Sheets("Infection" & Chr(97) & "Worksheet").Visible = True`

etc etc etc

Comment: Underscores are only continuation characters if preceded by whitespace, and not within a String literal.

Comment: Well his sheet is behaving as though nothing is in front of the underscore so that was my first suspect :)  I've had similar problems in the past.  It's usually misplaced quotes or using line continuation where I shouldn't though!

Comment: I hadn't noticed that the "object" being complained about was `_Worksheet`, so you may have hit on something, but not specifically due to the underscore character.  It could be some sort of corruption in the line (I saw another question recently where my solution was for the OP to simply retype the line).  @MarkPenno - try deleting and retyping the `Sheets("Infection_Worksheet").Visible = True` line.